# Using dataURI to preload video / audio

Tags: html, html5-video, data-uri

It seems we cannot preload html5 video in iOS or android. Can we transform the video / audio file in dataURI format and preload it?

Answer (score 0):

If you have the video in memory then you can use [URL.createObjectURL()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URL/createObjectURL) to a get url that points to the in-memory object and set this url as a `src` to the video element.

You can also try experimenting with the [preload](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_video_preload.asp) property and see if it works for you and for your target platforms.